# When does spring use application-dev.properties vs application.properties

Tags: maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea, application.properties

I've got several Spring Boot applications. All of them are maven projects and in all of them, I have separate configuration files for different environments, like application.properties, application-dev.properties, application-uat.properties. When I run the application on from IDE it sometimes reads from application.properties file and sometimes from application-dev.properties file. I use IntelliJ IDEA for development and I haven't been able to figure out what determines which file to read from. Is it IDE dependent or is there some configuration in Spring that decides which properties file to pick?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Most probably some of your Run configurations in Idea have configured Spring "profile" to run with. When you run Spring Boot application with, e.g., "dev" profile, then `application-dev.properties` file will be read in addition to `application.properties`. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config) for more info

Comment: Thanks for "in addition to". I had a property configured in application.properties, that was not defined in application-dev.properties. So the property from the first file was used, and that broke the application.